# Rails helper with block and using current_page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying to build a block helper but I cant seem to figure out a way to get access to current_page? from within the class.

My helper file looks like this:

```
class NavList

    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

    def header(title)
        content_tag :li, title, class: 'nav-header'
    end

    def link(title, path, opts={})

        content_tag :li, link_to(title, path), class: opts[:class]
    end

end

    def nav_list(&block)
    new_block = Proc.new do
        helper = NavList.new
        block.call(helper)
    end
    content_tag :ul, capture(&new_block), class: 'nav nav-list'
end
```

and i can use the helper via

```
<%= nav_list do |nl| %>
    <%= nl.header 'Location' %>
    <%= nl.link 'Basic Information', url_for(@department), class: current_page?(@departments) ? 'active' : '' %>
    <%= nl.link 'Employees', department_users_path(@department) %>
<% end %>
```

But what I would like to do is to not have to constantly take on that active class.
So I would like to do something like this

```
 def link(title, path, opts={})
    css_class = 'inactive'
    css_class = 'active' if current_page?(path)
content_tag :li, link_to(title, path), class: opts[:class]
 end
```

But i cant find a way to use current_page? from within the NavList class. It compains about a request method not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a better way though

```
class NavList
attr_accessor :request
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

    def header(title)
        content_tag :li, title, class: 'nav-header'
    end

    def link(title, path, opts={class: ''})
      opts[:class] = "#{opts[:class]} active" if current_page?(path)
        content_tag :li, link_to(title, path), class: opts[:class]
    end

end


def nav_list(&block)
    new_block = Proc.new do
        helper = NavList.new
        helper.request = request
        block.call(helper)
    end
    content_tag :ul, capture(&new_block), class: 'nav nav-list'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) the current_page? method requires the request object, maybe you could try passing the request object directly into the link method.

```
def link(title, path, request, opts={})
    css_class = 'inactive'
    css_class = 'active' if current_page?(path)
    content_tag :li, link_to(title, path), class: opts[:class]
 end

<%= nl.link 'Employees', department_users_path(@department), request %>
```

Comment: I managed to do it piggy backing the request object to the class from the helper... So i didnt have to specify it in the link code

Comment: That is a much cleaner solution!